# MultiLenguage XML for php integration

Tags: php, xml

i have a web site, in where i want to show some strings that may change according to the user lenguage and other parameters. I was thinking in a xml file like:

```
<strings>
<EN>
<userop1>This is the option 1<userop2>
</EN>
<ES>
<userop1>Esta es la opcion 1<userop1>
</ES>
</strings>
```

Then, using php something like: `echo("You select: ".$userop1);`

I really dont know if this is the most inteligent way to strutture the xml, so im asking for suggestiona (please with an example reading script). Thanks for any help!

Comment: Unless it's for learning purposes (which is fine), there are existing libraries for this, e.g. [Zend_Translate](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.translate.html).

Comment: @Andre This is the answer, not a comment.

Comment: @freela - ok, sorry... Made it as an answer

Answer (score 2):

Why are you using XML, this is an OVER HEAD in performance.

you should use Constants or Arrays.

```
$lang['en']['title'] = "title";
```

or separate files for each constants set/language
**file: tranlate.en.php**

```
defile('TITLE' , 'title');
```

since PHP is stateless, every page hit in your app will cause the system to parse this string.
no need for that

Answer (score 0):

I think you shouldn't have all languages in a single xml file - it may get too big, will be harder to maintain, and so. Instead, make a xml for each language.